# Show the command before execution and execute only after enter

Tags: bash

Often I copy paste command from text editor to shell.

Is there any way to  show the command(after pasting) and to execute only after pressing enter.

This way I can see the command first before execution and avoid problematic situations.

maybe another way to ask the same question is:
Is there configuration in bash to stop executing command on encountering newline and execute on manual newline by user ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231804/in-bash-how-to-add-are-you-sure-y-n-to-any-command-or-alias

Comment: Why do you paste stuff into the shell you haven't seen?

Comment: @Sven sometimes I am not sure what I have copied :)

Comment: @kumar ouch....

Answer (score 0):

type a quote `'` or `"` char before pasting.

if the line looks good, jump to the beginning (something like HOME or CTRL+a) and DEL the quote char and hit enter. Hit CTRL+c to throw away the entire multi-line paste.

If there are quote chars of the same kind in the clipboard when you paste, that will be a problem with this process.

Comment: You could use `#` instead to make the command a comment.

Comment: I read this as a multi-line paste.  if there is only one new-line, then yes, a comment at the start of the line would do.  As a side-effect, that would _probably_ store it in history too.

Comment: Agree on the multi-line paste. To prevent the line from being stored in history, you could start with a space before the `#`, and if `HISTCONTROL` has either `ignorespace` or `ignoreboth`, the line wouldn't end up in the history.